# Impossible to presentViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access

I've created a new application view based.
Here some the main code:

```
// AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    MIAPreferences *preferences;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MIAPreferences *preferences;

// AppDelegate.m

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navigationController;
@synthesize preferences;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *rootController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                            initWithRootViewController:rootController];
    navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]
                   initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    _window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}



// HomeViewController.m

-(IBAction)openLogin
{
    LoginViewController *view = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    // 1
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];

    // 2
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];

    // 3
    [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

All 3 options returns a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=....)

Can you please help me understand how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

The problem was due to a UIButton apparence set up during AddDelegate loading....but the first button was in the UIView I was going to load... that's why it crashed -.-"

Answer (score 1):

It could either mean: (1) The pointer used to point to memory that was ok, but its chunk was deallocated or (2) The pointer is corrupt. You can try to use zombie mode, if you aren't already, to get more information. In XCode press the Command, option, and I keys and a screen should pop up. Selected the Run option in the left hand side, then Diagnostics, and under memory management enable zombie objects should be checked.

Comment: Zombies are already on...but nothing showed. self.navigationController and view are not nil

Comment: Have you tried giving the initWithNibName: an actual nib? If it does work, then you should probably have a switch case or some if statement that changes the nibs depending on the certain case? Also are you using storyboard?

Comment: I'm not using storyboard.... and I've tried also using the nib name but nothing change :(

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `view` after `initWithNibName:`. `init`'ing with a `nil` nib name looks wrong to me, and you may be trying to push a `nil` view controller onto your navigation stack.

Comment: both self.navigationController and view are not nil